# Property of minimal projective resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I'm reading Dave Benson's book "Representations and Cohomology," Volume I, and I'm stuck on the proof of corollary 2.5.4 :

If $M$ is a module for an Artinian ring $\Lambda$ and $S$ is a simple $\Lambda$-module, then  \begin{eqnarray*}\text{Ext}^n_{\Lambda}(M,S)\cong \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(\Omega^nM,S).\end{eqnarray*}

Proof:
Let \begin{eqnarray*}\dots \rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_0\end{eqnarray*} be a minimal projective resolution of $M$. Then the complex 
        \begin{eqnarray*}\text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(P_0,S)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(P_1,S)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(P_2,S)\rightarrow \dots\end{eqnarray*}
        has zero differential, since if the composite $P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow S$ is non-zero, then $P_n$ has a summand isomorphic to the projective cover of $S$ and which is in the image of $P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n$ and hence in the kernel of $P_n\rightarrow P_{n-1}$, contradicting the minimality of $P_n$. Hence 
        \begin{eqnarray*}
   \text{Ext}^n_{\Lambda}(M,S) &=& \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(P_n,S) =  \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(P_n/\text{im}(P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n),S)\\
    &=& \text{Hom}_{\Lambda}(\Omega^nM,S).
  \end{eqnarray*}
$\square$

I understand that a minimal projective resolution exists under these conditions. I do not understand why $P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow S$ being non-zero yields a direct summand of $P_n$ isomorphic to the projective cover of $S$.

As far as I know, the only reasonable way of getting direct summands is by using Fitting's lemma. I can consider the diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lll}
 &  & P_S & & \\
 & & \da{\lambda} & & \\
P_n & \ra{f} & S & \ra{} &0\\
 & & \da{} &\\
&&0&
\end{array}
$$

Here, $P_S$ is the projective cover of $S$. The map $f:P_n\rightarrow S$ is surjective since we assume that the composition $P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n\xrightarrow{f} S$ is non-zero and $S$ is simple. By projectivity, there's a map $p:P_S\rightarrow P_n$ making this diagram commute. Similarly, we have a map $q:P_n\rightarrow S$ such that $\lambda q =f$. It follows that $pq\in \text{End}(P_n)$. Hence, by Fitting's lemma, $P_n=\text{im}((pq)^m)\oplus \ker((pq)^m)$ for some m>0.

I don't know how to proceed, I'm not able to show that one of these summands is the desired one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Q$ is a projective module and $f : Q \to S$ is a homomorphism, then there exists a map $f' : Q \to P_S$ with $f = \pi \circ f'$ with $\pi : P_S \to S$ the canonical epimorphism. The important thing to note is that if $f$ is surjective, then $\text{im}(f') + \ker(\pi) = P_S$. As $\ker(\pi)$ is superfluous (it is the radical of $P_S$) we conclude that $f'$ is surjective and using the projectivity of $P_S$ we conclude that $0 \to \ker(f') \to Q \to P_S \to 0$ is a split exact sequence, hence $P_S$ is a direct summand of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

To do this by Fitting, $P_S= \operatorname{im} (qp)^r \oplus \ker (qp)^r$ for some $r$, and one of these is zero as $P_S$ is indecomposable. Since $\lambda (qp)^r=\lambda$ we can't have $(qp)^r=0$ so $\operatorname{im}(qp)^r=P_S$ and $q$ is surjective. Now as Matthias says
$$ 0 \to \ker q \to P_n \to P_S \to 0$$ is exact and $P_S$ projective, so $P_S | P_n$.

Comment: Thank you, it's annoying when you're stuck on something so easy for far too long and you miss the obvious ways to do it. But again, thank you, this argument is simple and clear.

Comment: You're welcome. The key thing when you are stuck like this is to go back and question your assumptions about the way to approach the problem (e.g. you wanted to use Fitting on $P_n$, but maybe $P_S$ was easier).  Polya's How to Solve It is worth a read.